# ANTLR: empty condition not working

Tags: antlr

I want to be able to parse *int []* or *int* tokens.

Consider the following grammar:

```
TYPE    :   'int' AFTERINT;
AFTERINT:   '[' ']';
```

Of course it works, but only for *int []*. To make it work for *int* too, I changed `AFTERINT` to this (added an empty condition':

```
AFTERINT:   '[' ']' |
              |;
```

But now I get this warning and error:

> [13:34:08] warning(200): MiniJava.g:5:9:  Decision can match input
>   such as "" using multiple alternatives: 2, 3
>
> As a result, alternative(s) 3 were disabled for that input [13:34:08]
>   error(201): MiniJava.g:5:9: The following alternatives can never be
>   matched: 3

Why won't empty condition work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lexer cannot cope with tokens that match empty string. If you think about it for a moment, this is not surprising: after all, there are an infinite amount of empty strings in your input. The lexer would always produce an empty string as a valid token, resulting in an infinite loop.

The recognition of types does not belong in the lexer, but in the parser:

```
type
 : (INT | DOUBLE | BOOLEAN | ID) (OBR CBR)?
 ;

OBR     : '[';
CBR     : ']';
INT     : 'int';
DOUBLE  : 'double';
BOOLEAN : 'boolean';
ID      : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
```

Whenever you start combining different *type* of characters to create a (single) token, it's usually better to create a parser rule for this. Think of lexer rules (tokens) as the smallest building block of your language. From these building blocks, you *compose* parser rules.

Comment: Thank you Bart for the second time this week :) I was able to resolve the problem now and hope it will also help future ANTLR-help-seekers!

Comment: Do you remember your solution @c0dehunter ?

Comment: @doc I think c0dehunter solved it by applying my suggestion.

Comment: Exactly, I applied Mr. Kiers' solution above an it worked well.