# Can I match an empty function argument with ANTLR?

Tags: compiler-errors, antlr4

I need to be able to recognize an empty argument to a function with ANTLR.  For a given function, I would like to be able to support any argument being empty when parsing and the fact that a non-empty argument could have whitespace around the argument, e.g.:

```
f(x,y,)     parse args --> {x,y,empty}
f(x,,z)     parse args --> {x,empty,z}
f(x, ,z)    parse args --> {x,empty,z}
f( x , y, ) parse args --> {x,y,empty}
```

I am playing with a toy example at [lab.antlr.org](http://lab.antlr.org/).  I have the following:

**Lexer**

```
// DELETE THIS CONTENT IF YOU PUT COMBINED GRAMMAR IN Parser TAB
lexer grammar ExprLexer;

AND : 'and' ;
OR : 'or' ;
NOT : 'not' ;
EQ : '=' ;
COMMA : ',' ;
SEMI : ';' ;
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
LCURLY : '{' ;
RCURLY : '}' ;

INT : [0-9]+ ;
ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
WS: [ \t\n\r\f]+ -> skip ;
```

**Parser**

```
parser grammar ExprParser;
options { tokenVocab=ExprLexer; }

program
    : stat EOF
    | def EOF
    ;

stat: ID '=' expr ';'
    | expr ';'
    ;

def : ID '(' ID (',' ID)* ')' '{' stat* '}' ;

expr: ID
    | INT
    | WS*
    | func
    | 'not' expr
    | expr 'and' expr
    | expr 'or' expr 
    ;

func : ID '(' expr (',' expr)* ')' ;
```

**Input**

```
f(x,y,) {
    a = 3;
    x and y;
}
```

Running this code does actually give me the function definition with three arguments and the third one being empty, but there is an error with the rest of the parsing:

```
1:8 mismatched input '{' expecting {'and', 'or', ';'}
```

Linked question: [ANTLR: empty condition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289263/)

Comment: As a lexer or parser rule? Between what two characters? Any characters? `empty::;` is not a valid Antlr rule, so it cannot even parse whatever grammar you tried to generate a parser and lexer.

Comment: I think parser.  I have made the question clearer with a concrete example.

Comment: You cannot reference the lexer symbol `WS` in any rule. It is marked "skip", which means that there is no token emitted for that rule, and you cannot reference it in a parser rule. Remove that alt from `expr` entirely. In addition, you need to update `func` to be able to have "missing" arguments. `func: ID '(' empty_or_expr (',' empty_or_expr)* ')'; empty_or_expr : expr | ;`

Comment: Thanks, I did think that must be wrong

Comment: @kaby76 thanks. this change resolves the parameters, but I still get an error in the rest of the toy example.  The error is with the open brace.  For the following input `f(x , , y,) {` first line, I get this error: `1:12 mismatched input '{' expecting {'and', 'or', ';'}`.

Comment: Well, that's because the answer isn't exactly correct if you are using the "Antlr interpreter", as with lab.antlr.org. If you ran the grammar through the Antlr tool to generate a parser, it outputs "rule def contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string". The rule for "def" should be `def : ID '(' param (',' param)* ')' '{' stat* '}' ;` not `def : ID '(' (param (',' param)* )? ')' '{' stat* '}' ;`. A kleene operator (e.g., `(...)?`) should not be applied to an expr that derives empty (e.g., `param (',' param)*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing comma is invalid. If you want to support that, do this:

```
def : ID '(' param (',' param)* ')' '{' stat* '}' ;

param
 : ID
 | /* nothing */
 ;
```

This will support `f(x,y,) {}`, `f(x,y) {}`, `f(x,,,,y) {}` *and* `f() {}`

Comment: Thank you, this is useful.  Would you be able to help it support f(x,,z) f(x, y ,   ),  Basically, any argument could be empty a non-empty argument could have whitespace around it.

Comment: @doc, the spaces are already skipped in the lexer, so those are not an issue in the parser.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. I got what I needed in my project from your answer and the other comments from @kaby76, but this answer gives an error in the toy sample: `warning: 22:0: rule def contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string` and also fails at the brace `1:8 mismatched input '{' expecting {'and', 'or', ';'}`.  Would be good to fully fix the toy example for a complete answer to the question.

Comment: @doc ah yes, since `param` can match nothing, the part `( param (',' param)* )?` causes that warning. Instead of that, just do `param (',' param)*`. I've updated the complete warning-free parser rule in my answer.